# Apply new rotation and location to entire Animation

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms

I have a zombie model that I already animated and it's crawling.
However it's crawling in wrong direction - when I import it to Unity I can see that I am off the proper rotation by 180 degrees, this could have been prevented if I checked before animating.

I also didn't move the zombie along the Z axis to the floor, so it's in mid air.

What I would like to do now is fix this by applying that 180 degrees rotation and new position to the whole animation.

Take a look at this comparison:

[image: Comparison]

What I managed to do is to select all bones at the first frame and just rotate it, then import this into Unity. It works fine, but as soon as I play the animation inside blender it gets reset and all messed up (the animation rotates and moves back), so is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate any animation that is stuck on an axis like this one, remove rotation on all axes for your root bone, then rotate that root bone in position in which you want your model to be.